# Python decrypting bytes with special characters

Tags: python, encryption, aes

I'm trying to decrypt UDP packets sent between my phone and a smart plug. The packets are encrypted with AES 256 encryption but I have the key. Each smart plug generates a random set of characters to act as the password for that device. When decrypting the packet, the decryption fails with special characters.

I'm fairly new to encryption/decryption, however I've tried to format the packets before decryption but haven't had any luck.

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

def decrypt(encrypted_hex):

    enc_bytes = binascii.unhexlify(bytes(encrypted_hex,"utf-8")
    key = 'fdsl;mewrjope456fds4fbvfnjwaugfo'.encode()
    decryptor = Cipher(algorithm=algorithms.AES(key), mode=modes.ECB(),
                       backend=default_backend()).decryptor()

    decrypted = decryptor.update(enc_bytes) + decryptor.finalize()
    print(decrypted)
    return decrypted
```

As an example, the output I get is:

`device%28-d9-8a-8d-a4-ef\x00\xe9\x8f\x00pj*?`

Most of the packet, including the last 4 characters of the password are successfully displayed, however not all of the characters. I should mention as well that the key is public knowledge for these smart plugs and this decryption python script was posted online.

The raw UDP packet I am attempting to decrypt is: `c0405f7ac949afc673380ca145ee83746543a6368ec9f6fab08d714a2bb528c2`

Comment: More directly - what makes you think that the result you are getting is incorrect?  Do you have an example of a correct plaintext?

Comment: Hmm that is a good point. I think that "\x00\xe9\x8f\x00" is the section that I believe to be incorrect. I get the error: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 18-19: invalid continuation byte...


A similar output which properly decoded is:
lan_device%28-d9-8a-8d-f4-89%p3@Tq`dK%open#hv1.1.4#us1.1.0#1001%hack

Comment: Is there a guarantee that the result will be valid UTF8?

Comment: I don't think so. The plug generates a random password and I don't know how it generates it or what it generates.